# How to stop location tracking in app?

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I wrote a simple run tracking app. The location manager gets initialized when the user presses a start running button. But even after they press stop to stop location updates, ios continues to indicate thatnapp is using location tracking. How/what do I need to turn off apart from telling location manager to stop updates? This continues even after the view controller is destroyed and user has popped back to the main menu.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Show your tried code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
[locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
locationManager = nil;
```